# How to install PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am running OS X El Capitan v. 10.11.3

I am trying to install PyAutoGUI

On Terminal, I did the following successfully:

```
sudo pip3 install pyobjc-core  
sudo pip3 install pyobjc
```

When I tried running "sudo pip3 install pyautogui" I got the following error in Terminal:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/tmp/pip-build-skuvquyu/pyscreeze

I am not sure what to do about this so if anyone has any advice, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Found an answer to the problem

On Linux, this is:

```
sudo pip3 install python3-xlib

sudo apt-get install scrot

sudo apt-get install python3-tk

sudo apt-get install python3-dev

sudo pip3 install pyautogui
```

ta daaaa :D

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful!

Comment: I'm Happy that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a problem with pip. Try reinstalling it.

It'd be much better if you installed pyautogui directly from github.

Step 1:

```
git clone https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui
```

Step 2:

```
cd pyautogui
```

Step 3:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

If python3 doesn't work, try python.

Answer (score 1):

Now im using Ubuntu 14.04, but I would try installing the problematic module `pyscreeze` with:

```
sudo pip3 install pyscreeze
```

---

I personally got another error about missing module called PIL

```
sudo pip3 install pillow
```

And then i got some error message about jpeg `ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting`

I hope you'll have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

This installation error has most likely been fixed as of version 0.9.34. The module tried to load the PIL/Pillow module during installation.

Answer (score -1):

i have installed pyautogui on my windows :

1. I went to my python directory
2. There shift + right mouse click and open the command prompt
3. Type "python -m pip install pyautogui" (without quotes)

Comment: Windows, eh? Question is asking about *OS X*. Certainly these instructions cannot possibly be used as-is.