# ImportError: No module name pyautogui

Tags: python, terminal, cron, pyautogui

In raspberry pi terminal, I am getting

```
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

but the code runs perfectly fine in Thonny python IDE

I am trying to schedule a code (code.py) using crontab but the code is not running
probably because of ImportError

```
import pyautogui
```

Comment: In crontab, use the path to a python in a viirtualenv, or check for which python version is run.

Comment: check module using python3 -c "import pyautogui"

Comment: On changing python version now script is running directly through terminal but still not through crontab. I wrote /usr/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/code.py in crontab in place of /path/to/file

Comment: am still stuck, hope you'll help

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have `pyautogui` to install `pyautogui` you need to write this command:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got the same error message, and I found that you can solve this in two ways. Make sure that you have installed all dependencies properly. You can try to install these dependencies:

```
image==1.5.27
numpy==1.17.4
Pillow==6.2.1
requests==2.22.0
opencv-python
olefile==0.46
PyAutoGUI==0.9.48
PyMsgBox==1.0.7
pyobjc-core==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==6.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==5.3
PyScreeze==0.1.26
PyTweening==1.0.3
pathlib
```

Add these to your `requirements.txt` file.

`$cd`
into your project folder and run this installation command `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the required binaries. This should solve the problem.

Please make sure that you are using `python version > 3.5` as I found that `pyautogui` installation is sometimes not compatible with `python versions <3.5` so I recommend using `version 3.6`. You can easily create a `virtual environment` for your project using `pyenv` and manage multiple version of `python versions` by switching through them with `$pyenv shell <python-version>`

Comment: Alternatively you also check out this discussion, I think it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939986/how-to-install-pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

You can try also `pip install pywinauto`

Both of them are similar.